# Strange RTL output

Tags: yosys

[Yosys 0.8]

A colleague of mine threw some **random** verilog code to Yosys to see how it reacts.

Here it is:

```
module top(input clk, input led, output led2, output to_port1,output [24:0] to_port2);


reg ctr = 0;
reg[24:0] counter = 2;
always@(posedge clk) begin
    if (ctr == 1) begin
        ctr <= 0;
        counter <= counter + 1;
    end
    else
        ctr <= 1;
end

assign led2 = ctr;
assign to_port1 = led;
assign to_port2 = counter;
endmodule
```

and Yosys, with command `yosys -o synth.v x.v` throws:

```
module top(clk, led, led2, to_port1, to_port2);

  reg [24:0] _0_;
  reg _1_;
  reg [24:0] _2_;
  reg _3_;
  wire [31:0] _4_;
  wire _5_;
  input clk;
  reg [24:0] counter;
  reg ctr;
  input led;
  output led2;
  output to_port1;
  output [24:0] to_port2;

  assign _4_ = counter + 32'd1;
  assign _5_ = ctr == 32'd1;
  always @* begin
    _3_ = 1'h0;
  end
  always @* begin
  end
  always @({  }) begin
      ctr <= _3_;
  end
  always @* begin
    _2_ = 25'h0000002;
  end
  always @* begin
  end
  always @({  }) begin
      counter <= _2_;
  end
  always @* begin
    _1_ = ctr;
    _0_ = counter;
    casez (_5_)
      1'h1:
        begin
          _1_ = 1'h0;
          _0_ = _4_[24:0];
        end
      default:
          _1_ = 1'h1;
    endcase
  end
  always @(posedge clk) begin
      ctr <= _1_;
      counter <= _0_;
  end
  assign led2 = ctr;
  assign to_port1 = led;
  assign to_port2 = counter;
endmodule
```

Some constructs end up being complicated. This result code above cannot be compiled by recent verilog compilers when the original can.

Why the `always @({  }) begin` construct and empty `always @* begin`?
Is there an option we missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general you should always run proc (-p proc) between reading and writing Verilog, due to the nature of Yosys' internal representation of the read-in Verilog